# Solve $a_1^2 + 2a_2^2 + 3a_3^2 + ... + na_n^2 = a_{n+1}^2$ for natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

Solve the equation $\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot a_k^2 = a_{n+1}^2$ in natural numbers (i.e. $a_n \in \mathbb N~~ \forall n \in \mathbb N$).

I really have no idea as to how to approach the issue. A starter hint would be nice! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $a_1=a_2$, then look at $n=2$.

Comment: If it is a system for all natural $n$, then take $a_1^2+2a^2_2+\cdots+na^2_n=a^2_{n+1}$ and add $(n+1)a^2_{n+1}$ to both sides, you get $a_1^2+2a^2_2+\cdots+na^2_n+(n+1)a^2_{n+1}=a^2_{n+1}+(n+1)a^2_{n+1}=(n+2)a_{n+1}^2$, I would continue from here

Comment: @Alessandro So we obtain $(n + 2)a_{n+1}^2 = a_{n+2}^2 \Rightarrow a_{n+2} = \sqrt{n + 2}a_{n+1}$. So recursively, we can obtain the solution $a_n = \sqrt{n!}a_1$ for a chosen starting $a_1$. But how do we go further to prove it's all only natural?

Comment: @Mindlack If $a_1 = a_2$ and $n = 2$, then we otain $3a_1^2 = a_3^2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{a_3}{a_1} = \sqrt{3}$. Isn't that a contradiction? Does that mean there are no solutions?

Comment: @D.Petrov: that’s what I meant indeed (there the zero sequence, but it’s the only one).

Answer (score 3):

A second general solution occurs when $a_k=k\cdot A$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k\cdot A)^2=A^2\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=A^2\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$
The final term is a perfect square for all values of $n$.

In this case, $a_{n+1}=A\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: as per solution $a_n=A\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ hence for $n=1$ we get $a_1=0$ where as it is given in question that $a_i\in N \forall   i =1,2,3....$

Comment: @mathdiscussion You misunderstand the form of the result, which cannot be backward extrapolated. For all $1\le k\le n,\ a_k=kA$ is a starting assumption. Thereupon $a_{n+1}$ AND ONLY $a_{n+1}$ has the form $A\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. $a_n$ still has the form $nA$.

Answer (score 2):

**All** solutions in natural numbers can be found as follows.

Let $a_2,a_3,...,a_n$ be **any** natural numbers such that $$T= 2a_2^2 + 3a_3^2 + … + na_n^2$$ is either odd or divisible by $4$. Let $T=D\times E$ be any factorisation of $T$ with $D-E$ even.

Then $a_1=\frac{|D-E|}{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{D+E}{2}$ solve the equation because $a_{n+1}^2-a_1^2=DE$.

> EXAMPLE Starting with the 'arbitrary' choice $ 2\times4^2+3\times3^2+4\times1^2=63$.

We have the three factorisations $63=63\times 1$, $63=9\times 7$ and $63=21\times 3$. So there are three solutions.

$$(a_1,a_5)\text { is any one of } (31,32),(1,8),(9,12). $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is ONE non-zero solution for the special case that $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=A$. In that case $\sum ka_k^2=A^2\sum n=A^2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. If that sum equals a perfect square, then $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ must be a perfect square. This occurs when the even member of $n,(n+1)$ is twice a square, and the odd member is itself a square. Such numbers are called [square triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number). The first occurrence of that (for $n>1$) is $n=8$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^8 kA^2=36A^2$$
In this case that results in $a_{n+1}=6A$.

There may be more general solutions, and if I come across one, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

$a_1^2+2a^2_2+\cdots+na^2_n=a^2_{n+1}\tag{1}$

Substitute  $a_1=1+m_1t, a_2=0+m_2t, a_3=0+m_3t, \cdots,a_n=0+m_nt,a_{n+1}=1+m_{n+1}t$  to equation $(1)$, then we get  $$t=-2(m_1-m_{n+1})/(m_1^2+2m_2^2+3m_3^2+\cdots+nm_n^2-m_{n+1}^2).$$
Thus, we get a parametric solution.
$m_n$ is arbitrary.

Example for $n=3:$
\begin{eqnarray}
&a_1& = -m_1^2+2m_2^2+3m_3^2-m_4^2+2m_1m_4  \\ 
&a_2& =-2m_2(m_1-m_4)  \\ 
&a_3& = -2m_3(m_1-m_4)  \\ 
&a_4& = m_1^2+2m_2^2+3m_3^2+m_4^2-2m_1m_4  \\ 
\end{eqnarray}

$(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)=(1,1,2,2):  (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(13, 2, 4, 15)$
$(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)=(1,2,3,4):  (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(13, 6, 9, 22)$
$(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)=(4,3,2,1):  (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(7, 6, 4, 13)$